# On a typical COW filesystem, is the database WAL redundant (in theory)?

Tags: transaction-log, write-ahead-logging, file-system

EDIT: I was incorrectly assuming that all COW filesystems have a WAL. IT seems that BTRFS doesn't, so this question essentially applies only to ZFS.

Typical COW filesystems, like ZFS, have their own form of WAL (ZIL, in the case of ZFS).

On a non-COW filesystem, the DB WAL makes sense for both performance (because it's sequential) and integrity reasons (because of the lack of write integrity guarantees); on a COW filesystem, those roles are fulfilled by the FS (WAL).

Because of this, doesn't storing DB data on a COW filesystem make the DB WAL redundant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, because the WAL is also used for restoring from backups -- for example, in case of user error. In combination with a prior full backup, it allows restoring to any point in time -- presumably prior to when the user did something bad.

Comment: Good point. I think restores can be achieved also by storing and replaying the filesystem WAL log, however, since they are at a lower level than the database, they  could be associated to absolute time, but not to db write operations.

Comment: Don’t forget also that the backup and WAL can be restored on any machine, not necessary the same one. In theory a file system could provide the features for a database to do its ACID compliance, but I don’t think any filesystems provide all the needed features to do ACID, at the same level of granularity, while maintaining the same level of performance and retaining the ability to offer all the other DBMS features (tablespaces, partitions, etc).

Answer (score 1):

Also no because a transaction may require changing hundreds of different locations in a file, and copy-on-write does nothing to make that faster.  But write-ahead logging allows all the changes to be written in a minimal number on IOs, and applied to the data files later.  The later writes are asynchronous, and benefit from write coalescing, so a file location modified by many transactions may be written to only once.

Comment: I had incorrectly assumed that BTRFS had WAL, while it doesn't. If we talk about ZFS, what you're describing is the behavior of ZFS and ZIL - ZIL writes are serialized and synchronous, while pool writes are random and asynchronous.